# Breaking up long line imports into multiple line import

Tags: angular

I had a very long import statement with quite a few components being imported from a single source so I broke it up into two import statements for the same source - I was wondering if this is fine to do or if there's any implications of doing so? i.e.

```
import { A, B, C, D, E, F } from 'mypath';
```

becomes:

```
import { A, B, C } from 'mypath';
import { D, E, F } from 'mypath';
```

Comment: I don't think it matters how you import them. Those parts will be loaded when you'll actually refer them somewhere (as far as I know)

Comment: Sure, just wondered if there was any downside to importing them like this way i.e. performance as apposed to just importing once but adding a line break

Comment: Why not just put line breaks in there..? Prettier is a must have tool btw..

Comment: @MikeOne Yep that's an option, just thought this approach was more readable but was concerned there were implications with it

Answer (score 0):

to avoid warning

```
 import { A, B, C, D, E, F } from 'mypath';
```

can become

```
 import { A, B, C, 
 D, E, F,
 X,Y,Z } from 'mypath';
```

Answer (score -1):

It won't have an impact, but why do it? Instead use a standard Code Formatter Like Prettier to format your code. Also in VS code you can press F1 and choose Organize Imports Option to clean up your imports from unused imports.